# EditText text color is always white after applying ColorStateList

Tags: android, android-edittext, customization, attr, android-color

I have this problem:
I have a custom EditText that has a theme, as done for other components, I created a class that extends this EditText and in the onDraw method I applied a ColorStateList, I can correctly apply the colors I set, but text turns white and I would instead set it in the ColorStateList, how can I do, I am attaching the override of the onDraw () method, which as said works for the other components.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (!AppApplication.IS_DEFAULT) {
        ColorStateList thumbStates = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, 
                        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, 
                        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, 
                        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  

                },
                new int[]{
                        Color.BLACK,
                        Color.RED,
                        Color.GREEN,
                        Color.BLUE
                }
        );
        this.setBackgroundTintList(thumbStates);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you do that in onDraw() method? It is not white, it just doesn't draw. I don't see calling `super.onDraw(canvas)` here.

Comment: You're talking about text colour, but what you are setting here is background tint. Which one are you actually trying to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see here the following required corrections:

1. Don't set background Here. it will probably start an infinite loop of redrawing.
2. Call `setBackgroundTintList` from outside of the class, or at least in the constructor of the class (better the one with 2 parameters).

And for your case you don't need to override the method `onDraw(canvas)`, or at least if you still want to, follow the rules:

– call `super.onDraw(canvas)` if you want the class to draw it as usual.

– don't allocate memory in this method, which you do by creating this int arrays.